# Java output from list based on chance

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to figure out a method which as two arguments, one is a Object[] and the other a float[], both same size. the floats are the chances of the output being the corresponding object in the object list, object in index i has chance (0.0-1.0) stored in the float in index i. The values on the chance list all sum up to 1.0 if all summed up together.

The thing that I want this method to do is to return one of the objects from the list randomly, being the chance of each object of being picked inside the chance list. Example {banana, apple, orange} {0.1, 0.5, 0.4} Having 10% chance of returning banana, 50% apple and 40% orange.

Note: The method can't be for a fixed number of objects, so a hard-coded if chain won't work :/

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach to use a a variable to store the adumulated chance of a position in the array.

```
public Object randomObject(Object[] objects, float[] chances){
    //Implement here validations, about arrays size and chances values.

    float random = (float) Math.random();
    float acumulatedChance = 0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < chances.length; i++) {
        acumulatedChance += chances[i];
        if (acumulatedChance >= random) {
            return objects[i];
        }            
    }
    return objects[objects.length-1];        
}
```

Comment: **DON'T** create a new `Random` object each time the method gets called!  Make a static `Random` object and re-use it.

Comment: Since @Chapi asked for a method, my answer Is a self contained method for that requirement. Obviously there some improvements I could have made to this code.
One of the is to extract randomFloat generator to other function or service. And this function or service could be backed by a static Random field, anyway I prefer lazy loaded singletons for that purposes, also I should consider concurrency, Random is threadsafe but have performance issues in a multi-threaded environment.
A good answer should try to be concise to the problem, and adapted to the level of the asker.

Comment: A good answer should recommend best practices, and not recommend approaches with known problems.

Comment: If you want it to be self-contained, use `(float) Math.random()`.

Comment: I think `(float) Math.random()` fits better in this context. I'll update my anwser to include it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually Ezequiels answer was great, that's why I chose it as answer. Did exactly what I needed, I don't need optimization for this neither because of how I will be using it, but thanks anyway for the extra tips. Gotta admit best practices is very important as pjs said tho

Comment: @Chapi Ezequiel's answer is not as great as you think. `Random`'s distributional properties are guaranteed for a sequence of values generated from a single instance, *not* across multiple instances.  If you need more than one `randomObject`, you may not be getting the distributional behavior you think from this implementation.  It's such a simple fix to replace `new Random().nextFloat()` with `(float) Math.random()` and thus avoid any issues that could occur from instantiating `Random` multiple times, why would anybody choose not to do it correctly?

Comment: Yes it is true a single random should be instantiated outside methods and reused, I knew that already. It is just irrelevant for this question to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is count the number of appearances of each element in list.

Number of each appearances of an element in that list divided by the sum of all appearances equals the probability that element will randomly get picked from that list.

ArrayList can contain your elements.
You can count appearances of each element in an hash map or another ArrayList provided you keep track which index counts which element.

You will need to loop once through the element list to gather count data, after that simply calculate probabilities from that count data.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I already have the probability of each element, simply needed to pick one of them based on the probability given. Anyway the code from Ezequiel does exactly what I needed, thanks anyway